# Double Tapping Check Java

Tags: java, keyboard, awt

How do you apply a key listener for double tapping? That is, you hit once and it turns on, then you hit again and it turns off. I can do this though LWJGL Keyboard, but not though KeyEvent with AWT. How can you do this with AWT?

My Attempt:

```
public static void fullscreenKey(KeyEvent e2, JFrame frame)
{
    int key = e2.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_F1)
    {
        fullscreen(false, frame);
        f1 = false;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_F1 && !f1)
    {
        fullscreen(true, frame);
        f1 = true;
    }
}
```

I also need to call this method in other classes.

Comment: Basically any variation of this. I either hit once and it turns on, but then it flips from off back to on. I don't know any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are calling `fullscreen` twice:

```
public static void fullscreenKey(KeyEvent e2, JFrame frame)
{
    int key = e2.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_F1)
    {
        // This always executes if VK_F1 is pressed,
        // setting f1 to false
        fullscreen(false, frame);
        f1 = false;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_F1 && !f1)
    {
        // f1 is now false, so this will execute too!
        fullscreen(true, frame);
        f1 = true;
    }
}
```

You should maybe try:

```
public static void fullscreenKey(KeyEvent e2, JFrame frame)
{
    int key = e2.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_F1)
    {
        fullscreen(!f1, frame);            
        f1 = !f1;
    }     
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! I never thought about using the boolean in the method, thank you.

Comment: @Coupon22 Excellent. Please [mark it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) then so that others know your issue is solved.